# Clean Design to Handle Multiple Result Sets from IDataReader

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, c#-4.0

Maybe SO isn't the place for this, and I apologize if it's not, but I can't help but think there's a better way to do this.  This just seems like a gross and not very clean way of checking which result set I'm on and then performing a corresponding action.  Anyone have any suggestions?  (Please ignore the fact I'm always returning null).

```
public MemberDto Load(long entityId)
    {
        using (var cn = new SqlConnection(@"connectionstringstuff"))
        {
            cn.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cm = cn.CreateCommand())
            {
                cm.CommandText = "Client.[MemberGet]";
                cm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EntityId", entityId);

                using (IDataReader dr = cm.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    var memberModel = new MemberDto();
                    do
                    {
                        while (dr.Read())
                        {
                            var sdr = new SafeDataReader(dr);
                            var firstColumn = sdr.GetName(0);
                            if (firstColumn.StartsWith("Attribute"))
                            {
                                AddAttribute(memberModel, sdr);
                            }
                            else if (firstColumn.StartsWith("AlternateId"))
                            {
                                AddAlternateId(memberModel, sdr);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                memberModel.ClientId = sdr.GetInt64("ClientId");
                                memberModel.Id = sdr.GetInt64("EntityId");
                                memberModel.Name = sdr.GetString("EntityName");
                            }
                        }
                    } while (dr.NextResult());
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    private void AddAttribute(MemberDto model, SafeDataReader reader)
    {
        model.Attributes.Add(
            reader.GetInt32("AttributeTypeId").As<EntityAttributeType>(),
            reader.GetString("Value"));
    }

    private void AddAlternateId(MemberDto model, SafeDataReader reader)
    {
        model.Attributes.Add(
            reader.GetInt32("AlternateIdTypeId").As<EntityAttributeType>(),
            reader.GetString("Value"));
    }
```

Comment: Don't you know which resultset comes first?

Comment: Yeah, I control the SP.  I was just wanting to not having to rely on the order in case someone changes it in the future for one reason or another.  I'm not completely against it, but I was trying to shy away from it.

Comment: @phreak3eb that order should be considered part of the contract of the SP, IMO. If that changes, it should be expected that callers need changes.

Comment: Fair enough.  That being said, any suggestions if going by the order of the result sets?

Comment: It's inefficient, especially for large result sets, but you could add an initial column that specifies (names) the result set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way that we approach this is not to loop on the nextresult, but explicitly code it to match the underlying data. It is somewhat more visually obvious what the expected results are with this approach (in my opinion, of course).

Here is an example rewrite, assuming the order is membermodel, attributes, and alternates.

```
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        var sdr = new SafeDataReader(dr);
        memberModel.ClientId = sdr.GetInt64("ClientId");
        memberModel.Id = sdr.GetInt64("EntityId");
        memberModel.Name = sdr.GetString("EntityName");
    }
    if (dr.NextResult())
    {
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            AddAttribute(memberModel, new SafeDataReader(dr));
        }
    }
    if (dr.NextResult())
    {
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            AddAlternateId(memberModel, new SafeDataReader(dr));
        }
    }
```

Comment: After a lot of consideration and playing around, I keep going back to  Marc Gravell's original comment above in that the order of the result sets should be part of the contract of the proc.  That being said, I wish I could accept two answers because both competent_tech and tcarvin have bits of my solution in each.  I chose this answer because it doesn't involve sending back a metadata result set with each response.  So now I expect the result sets to be in a given order but also went with some specific classes to bind the records to the model. Thanks everyone for your input.

Comment: any sample about SafeDataReader ?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps all sp that return multiple resultsets should always include first a resultset specifiying which resultsets are returned in which order:

```
dr = multRsCmd.ExecureReader();

// first rs is always the meta
List<string> resultSetIds = new List<string>();
while (dr.Read())
   resultSetIds.Add(dr[0]

foreach (string rsId in resultSetIds)
{

   if (!dr.NextResult())
      break; // or throw, should not happen

   if (rsId == "ClientDataWithAttribute")
   {
      // code to handle the exact rs layout for ClientDataWithAttribute
      //
      //
   }
   else if (rsId == "ClientDataWithAltId")
   {
      // code to handle the exact rs layout for ClientDataWithAltId
      //
      //   
   }
   else if (rsId == "ClientData")
   {
      // code to handle the exact rs layout for ClientData
      //
      //   
   }

}
```

This of course screams out for refactoring:

```
dr = multRsCmd.ExecureReader();

// first rs is always the meta
List<string> resultSetIds = new List<string>();
while (dr.Read())
   resultSetIds.Add(dr[0]

foreach (string rsId in resultSetIds)
{

   if (!dr.NextResult())
      break; // or throw, should not happen

   // pull subclass out of registry of readers
   ResultSetReader rsr = ResultSetReaders.Find(rsId);

   // subclass cleanly holds the layout-dependent logic
   memberModel = rsr.FromDataReader(dr);

 }
```

That looks pretty clean, but you could even add default behavior in the ResultSetReader to drive the DTO property mapping from a config file or other source and only override when you get special conditions.  You get the idea.